# Linux pipe previous result at specific location

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

Consider the shell command like this

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python spark2-submit --driver-memory 40g --executor-memory 20g --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=7200 myfile.py param1 param2
```

I would like to pipe `my_file.py` as result of a previous command. It needs to be in that particular location because I will access param1 as `sys.argv[1]` later (`sys.argv[0]` being `my_file.py`). I have tried

```
previous_command_that_returns_myfile.py | PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python spark2-submit --driver-memory 40g --executor-memory 20g --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=7200 - param1 param2
```

but this does not seem to be the solution.
How would I indicate pipe result at a specific location like this ?

What I tried to do originally is to encrypt the file, then de-crypt and run

```
openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -in test.py > test_enc
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in test_enc | PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python spark2-submit --driver-memory 40g --executor-memory 20g --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=7200 - param1 param2
```

Updates : the command is spark2-submit, the first part is setting env variable. 
According to [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90178/how-can-i-either-encrypt-or-render-my-shell-script-unreadable) one method of writing is

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in script-enc | sh -
```

in which hyphen (-) seems to represents what I wanted. What is the exact meaning of hyphen here and why didn't it work in our case ?

Comment: I would try this in bash: `( previous_command_that_returns_myfile.py ) | /usr/bin/python spark2-submit …`  Also note that the command after the pipe is missing the leading slash '/'. Hopefully that is just a transcription error.

Comment: `What is the exact meaning of hyphen here` - inside `sh` code there is `if (arg[0] == '-') { then read from stdin }`. It has no special significance. Actually, it should work without `-` at all, as `bash` reads stdin by default. `why didn't it work in our case ?` - you have to handle it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Use process substitution with `<(command)`. It'll run the command and replace it with the file name of a pipe connected to the command's stdin or stdout.

```
python spark2-submit --driver-memory 40g --executor-memory 20g --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=7200 \
    <(previous_command_that_returns_myfile.py) param1 param2
```

Alternatively, if the Python script doesn't use stdin for anything else you can pipe the output in and tell it to read from `/dev/stdin`.

```
previous_command_that_returns_myfile.py |
    python spark2-submit --driver-memory 40g --executor-memory 20g --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=7200 \
    /dev/stdin param1 param2
```